# Adding a second Git repository to existing xcode project

Tags: git, xcode4, github

I inherited a codebase from a coworker who left the company. He designed a custom library to use with the code which he put in our company's github account. However, I don't know how to pull this library into the project on MY computer from github. I've managed to connect the project to the main code repository, but I don't know the step-by-step way to add the library. I don't have tons of experience using command line git, but if that's the only way, I'm willing to try it...

Answer (score 1):

I have a project in XCode composed of 2 separate git repositories. One is for the main host app and the other is for a separate number crunching library used by the host app.  The split was chosen as it would be nice to share the library as a more lightweight and independent body of code.

Just pull the separate library repository into a separate (not nested) directory on disk and then link to this library from the main XCode project by adding the source to the project. XCode will automatically show you when changes are made to either repo in the file browser. The project file layout and repositories are independent concepts. You could have a separate repo for every source file if you wanted to.

To pull the library on your local machine, first fork the repo to your own account and then pull it in using the instructions on the site . .

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

If you modify the library, remember to commit from the library directory. When you push, you will update your fork.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't fork the repository to my person git account because my account is public and the code is proprietary. Is there no way to just pull the code from this second repository just like I pull code from the main one?

Comment: You might be able to just download it directly. On a regular public page, there is a download link towards the top right.

Comment: I downloaded it no prob, and when I click on individual files on my desktop, they all load fine, but when I add them to the project, they all appear in red and the working code can't find them. I tried deleting and re-adding all the files, cleaning and building in between, but they won't work properly

Comment: Files in red normally indicate that something has been moved/deleted outside of the editor. Were the files part of the project before you downloaded you own copies?

Comment: Yes - when I pulled the entire project from our company git account, the library's files were already in the project (in red) so I was hoping if I just copied them from my desktop, it would fix the problem, but it just created two copies of each file, all in red

Comment: Ok, make a note of the files that need to be included in the project and then delete all of the files in red from within the XCode project (just remove references). Next, add the existing files to the XCode project from wherever you have them stored locally.

Comment: Ahh! I got it working - I reinstalled git, and then used the "submodule add" command, and added the separate repository and then I could import the files no problem. Thanks for all your suggestions and help!